# creating many to many relationship with keystone on existing database

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query, keystonejs

I want to add object reference in existing database.
    Right now i have both database(domains & LabConfigs)  up & running & they both have there instances which i could see from robomongo.

LabConfigs look like this

```
         id_:12345 (objectId)
         labConfig: test1
         id_:67890 (objectId)
         labConfig: test2
```

DomainName look like this

```
         id_:8787897 (objectId)
         domainName:ggogle.com
         id_:34234234 (objectId)
         domainName:fb.com
```

Now when i start my keystone, with following schema.

```
****************LabConfigs***********************
var LabConfigs = new keystone.List('LabConfigs');

LabConfigs.add({
 configName: {type: Types.Text, required: true, initial: true, index: true}
});
 LabConfig.defaultColumns = 'configName';
 LabConfig.register();

************************************************
```

And this is my second database.

```
var Domain = new keystone.List('Domain');

Domain.add({
  domainName: {type: Types.Text, required: true, initial: true, index: true},
  labConfigs :{type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'LabConfigs',required: false,many: true},
   userauthlevel:{ type: Types.TextArray}
  });


Domain.defaultColumns = 'domainName';
Domain.register();
```

Now I want is to add labConfigs in domain database as an array. i.e. each labConfigs has a relationship to domain array.

In keystone

1. Where to add in keystone starting i.e. to build this many to many relationship ?
2. Which query should i do build this relationship in that ( init ) function ?

Answer 1 --> I searched too much & figure out that it is good idea to have it in

```
 view.on('init', function())}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `labconfigs` field on your `Domain` model, and you've set `many: true` on it. Now you can specify an array of `LabConfig` IDs on the `Domain` document. When you save a `Domain`, you can set `labConfigs` to be equal to an array of `labConfig` document IDs. You can also create an array of `labConfig`s themselves, instead of their IDs. Keystone will save the references to the objects in the same way.

```
view.on('post', function (next) {
    var labConfigIDs = []; // Array of labConfig IDs, created however you want
    domain.getUpdateHandler(req).process({
        labConfigs: labConfigIDs
    }, {
        flashErrors: true,
        errorMessage: 'There was a problem updating your domain.'
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            req.flash("error", saveErr.message);
            return next();
        } else {
            req.flash('success', 'Your changes have been saved.');
            return next();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can i do same stuff initially when keystone start rather than view.on(post) . Can i do same thing on view.on('init) also ? You reply is good if we are getting new + inserting new  domain value whille i want it in starting. As my both collection exits .

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Models and their information persist in your database, so I don't see a need to do anything when keystone starts (`keystone.on('start')`. If you want to prepopulate some data once Keystone starts (dummy/test values), use its [built-in update functionality](http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/#updates).

Comment: userauthlevel is an array of text array. How to insert item in  userauthlevel?    userauthlevel is an array of string with value "true/false"  for each corresponding value in LabConfig array.